# Is there a way to make div render from right to left HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a project(calendar) and I want to convert it to arabic. I don't know if **render** is the right term, but all I want to do is to **show the div from right to left.**

I have a row(divs) with columns(divs).
**divs not texts**

Something like this

```
div1 div2 div3
div4 div5 div6
div7 div8 div9
```

to

```
div3 div2 div1
div6 div5 div4
div9 div8 div7
```

My project is responsive, so manually putting it backwards won't work.

This is what I mean with smaller resolution.

```
div2 div1
div4 div3
div6 div5
div8 div7
div9
```

Any solutions.. dirty or clean, hack or not will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: what is wrong with using `body { direction:rtl; ]}`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `float: right` on `div`s. This will render `div`s from right to left.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/x1sou51m/)

```css
#container div {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use css `direction` property to control how `inline` and `inline-block` elements are rendered.

HTML:

```
<div class="day day-1">1</div>
<div class="day day-2">2</div>
<div class="day day-3">3</div>
<div class="day day-4">4</div>
<div class="day day-5">5</div>
<div class="day day-6">6</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
.day {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

.day-1 {
    background: red;
}
.day-2 {
    background: green;
}
.day-3 {
    background: yellow;
}
.day-4 {
    background: blue;
}
.day-5 {
    background: lime;
}
.day-6 {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbzddcLc/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Html

```
<div id="container" dir="RTL">// you can use dir="RTL" global attribute
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

css

```
  #container div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/weoej4yn/

Answer (score 0):

with `flexbox`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item-a">...</div>
    <div class="item-b">...</div>
    <div class="item-c">...</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.item-a {
    order: 3;
}

.item-b {
    order: 2;
}

item-c {
    order: 1;
}
```

note that `flexbox` is not supported by older browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox