# Item alignment in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a navbar in my html bootstrap-based page that has these items:

```
item7 item6 item5 item4 item3 item2 item1
```

It is in Persian and should be arranged right to left.

When it loads on phone it shows items like this:

```
 - item7
 - item6
 - item5
 - item4
 - item3
 - item2
 - item1
```

How can I arrange them in this way:

```
 - item1
 - item2
 - item3
 - item4
 - item5
 - item6
 - item7
```

**css**:

```
element.style {
    text-align: right;
}
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ol, ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890735/is-there-a-way-to-make-div-render-from-right-to-left-html

Comment: @Amitsingh - I don't think that has anything to do with what the poster has asked... He's asking about the order of the items, not the styling. Also, how do you know that the poster is NOT using that class in his `ul` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi dude i think normally 
by applying float : right side of li's then you can achieve your way.

and you can apply them like this

```css
(your selector or ul ) li{
float : right;   //apply additional css styles
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not arrange the list items from right to left in the markup. Keep them in original order;

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Then, override the Bootstrap style of `.navbar-nav > li` for larger screen sizes to `float-right`.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav > li {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

This way, on large screen sizes when the `nav` is shown horizontally it will reverse your order. But, on smaller screen sizes when the list items are collapses, they will preserve the original order when shown vertically.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jwcagnwv/

.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend keeping the markup in its semantic order, as @Abhitalks suggested, but use RTL (Right To Left) in the document level.

That way, you don't have to mess around with floats at all.

There are RTL plugins for Bootstrap that make it easier for you, e.g. [morteza's](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl).